# Will a mass $m$ rotating around a black hole with mass $M$ form a new black hole together with $M$, at a close enough distance?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, everyday-life

A mass $m$ rotates around a black hole with mass $M$ at a distance $r$ from the horizon. The combined system has an energy depending on the mass $M$ and the rest energy and kinetic energy of $m$.

When the mass $m$ is rotating close to the horizon, its speed will approach the speed of light. Time will go slower though near the horizon, so the mass $m$ seems to slow down and have less energy.

What will happen? Is there a distance at which the combined system will form a new black hole so the horizon of $M$ is enclosed by this new hole?

Comment: A distant observer would see the mass orbiting with the Newtonian orbital speed.

Answer (score 1):

A massive object cannot be in a circular orbit arbitrarily close to a Schwarzschild black hole's event horizon.  There is an [innermost stable circular orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innermost_stable_circular_orbit) at radius $3 R_s$ (where $R_s$ is the event horizon radius), which is the closest stable circular orbit for any massive object.  *Unstable* orbits at closer radius are possible;  but these are, well, unstable, and the slightest perturbation will lead to the massive object either falling into the black hole or flying off to infinity.  What's more, such perturbations are literally unavoidable;  see the next paragraph. So for any "stable" orbit, the mass $m$ is well-separated from the black hole;  it can't orbit arbitrarily close to the event horizon.

Now, it's true that the mass $m$ will emit gravitational waves and thereby (slowly) lose energy.  This will cause the radius of the orbit to (slowly)  decrease, and eventually the mass $m$ will be orbiting so close that its orbit becomes unstable ($r < 3 R_s$).  Then it will plunge into the black hole and merge with it.  So in that sense, they will eventually merge.  The final mass of the black hole will then just be $m + M$, minus whatever amount of gravitational wave energy is emitted over the many aeons of its inspiral and plunge into the black hole, and minus whatever binding energy the orbiting mass originally had.

Comment: In principle correct, but the total energy of a particle in orbit is already less than mc², only if its velocity equals the escape velocity its total energy is mc², if it is less the black hole's mass measured at infinity will be less than M+m after the plunge (even when neglecting gravitational waves).

Comment: @Yukterez:  Good point.  Added a comment at the end.

Comment: > *they will eventually merge* But it will take infinite time, so is "eventually" right here? The two body configuration will effectively freeze before merging.

Comment: @safesphere:  "Binding energy" is the amount of energy that would be required to move the orbiting object from its current location to infinity.  This is why (as Yukterez noted) the total energy of an orbiting object is less than $mc^2$.